# possibility of interference of electrons during its transition from higher to lower state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wave-particle-duality

They say an electron possesses dual nature (what we call wave-particle duality in order to relate with our everyday world). If it is an electron (definite particle) it too shows wave-like phenomenon for certain. 
Then is there any possibility of interference of electrons during its transition from excited state to ground state (say from orbit n=4 to n=1) through second and third orbit?
Take the case in which there are already electrons in second and third orbits.

Comment: First of all, don't listen to them when they say that. :-) You _don't need_ wave-particle duality for anything and in reality it just gets in your way when you spend effort thinking about something that you never needed in the first place. The effect you perceive exists and it is usually taken care of by perturbation theory which sums over all possible intermediate states.